# Android: view pager effect in a listview item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

I have a list view with multiple items but my first item in list view is different from others.
The first item of the listview has horizontal scrollview which has three view inside it and they have on click listner set to them. Every things works well but when we scroll the horizontal scrollview  the view doesn't fits in place they are just scolled which make half of both the views visible,
I wanted to have a effect of view pager where when a item is scrolled it gets in focus while removing the previous item from the screen. i tried using scrollto method for scrolling the listview to be in position when the touch value lies in between specified range but couldn't get the proper animation

---

So should i use a view pager inside the listview or their any other way round, I basically want to implement that when user performs a swipe gesture on a listitem the view inside that item should change, similar to view pager

---

this is my sql code to show three view in horizontal scroll view

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back_strip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image2" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back_strip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="text2"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image3" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ back_strip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="text3"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

---

I was thinking can we use viewflipper or viewanimator to that we can change view on swipe gesture

Comment: PLease post some xml and code. That way we can try help easier

Comment: i am using scrollview to show other view on swipe but problem is on swipe the next view doesn't fit completely, the current and the next view both are shown , so i wanted to have a display like view pager where when we swipe a view the current get completely removed and the next get completely fit but the view in which i am going to use view pager is a part of listview, so is  feasible to use view pager inside listview or theirs any other way to implement it

Comment: i want want the when user swipes horizontally over the item in list view the view iside the listitem should change to the next one or prev on based of swipe motion

Comment: then why don't you use `ViewPager` instead of `HorizontalScrollView` ?

Comment: thnx for the suggestion, i used view pager and its working fine , i just wanted to check if theirs any  other way instead of view pager as i just need to modify single item of list-view .